# saving updated field play framework

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

This is a very basic problem, but I cannot seem to solve/figure out the problem so hoping some fresh eyes can help out.

I have a model User which has username and password. I want to allow Users to update their password, so I added update() method as shown below:

```
public static void update(User user) throws UserException {
    User record = User.getById(user.id);
    if (null == record) {
        throw new UserException(BaseException.invalidRecordMessageException(User.class.getSimpleName()));
    }

    if (!StringUtils.equals(record.username, user.username)) {
        throw new UserException(BaseException.unmodifiableFieldMessageException(User.class.getSimpleName(), "username"));
    }
    validatePassword(user.password);
    saveUser(user);
}
```

And here is my saveUser():

```
private static void saveUser(User user) {
    user.password = encryptPassword(user.password);
    user.save();
    System.out.println("n: " + user.id);
    System.out.println("n: " + user.username);
    System.out.println("n: " + user.password);

    User r = User.getById(user.id);
    System.out.println("r: " + r.id);
    System.out.println("r: " + r.username);
    System.out.println("r: " + r.password);
}
```

I added a test to confirm that the functionality is working perfectly.

```
@Test
public void testUpdateUserPasswordWithValidPasswordShouldUpdateRecord() {
    try {
        User dummy = new User(DEFAULT_USERNAME, DEFAULT_RAW_PASSWORD);
        User.create(dummy);

        assertNotNull(dummy.id);
        User record = User.getById(dummy.id);
        assertEquals(DEFAULT_USERNAME, record.username);
        assertEquals(DEFAULT_RAW_PASSWORD, record.password);

        dummy.password = DEFAULT_RAW_PASSWORD + "_extra";
        User.update(dummy);

        User updatedRecord = User.getById(dummy.id);
        assertEquals(dummy.username, updatedRecord.username);
        assertEquals(dummy.password, updatedRecord.password);
    } catch (UserException ue) {
        fail("Test should not throw exception.");
    }
}
```

However, the test is failing as the record does not seem to be updating:

```
Test UserTest.testUpdateUserPasswordWithValidPasswordShouldUpdateRecord failed: expected:<$uP3rsecretpassword[_extra]> but was:<$uP3rsecretpassword[]>
```

DEFAULT_PASSWORD = $uP3rsecretpassword

Here is the output of all System.out.println() calls:

--- initial create ---
n: 1

n: moo

n: $uP3rsecretpassword

r: 1

r: moo

r: $uP3rsecretpassword

--- update ---

n: 1

n: moo

n: $uP3rsecretpassword_extra

r: 1

r: moo

r: $uP3rsecretpassword

Thanks in advance to any help.

Comment: where is the save implementation?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem lies in this line:

```
    User record = User.getById(user.id);
```

Hibernate only keeps around *one* object of a certain id. So, here, you're effectively overwriting the change which is contained in the object `user` with the (old) state currently in the DB.

As for the checks you're doing there, they seem to be a bit superfluous anyways as you're not trusting your own code.